# Duplicate hidden form with not unique input ID

Tags: php, html, lighthouse

I have a layout that require to have the same form in 2 different place for mobile and desktop view

What I did is to wrap both in a container that hide one or another based on viewport size

I was testing with Google Lighthouse and it complains that form field ID are not unique
Any way to fix this without handle the 2 form field with different ID?

I always add input field with the same ID and NAME

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="" required>
```

I guess I will not have any issue with post variables if I differentiate ID while keeping field name the same

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name-mobile" name="name" value="" required>
```

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, so no, there is no way to do this without changing the IDs. _"I guess I will not have any issue with post variables if I differentiate ID while keeping field name the same"_ - no, of course not - IDs have no relevance whatsoever in creating the form submission data set. Question would be, whether IDs are _actually_ needed for anything in particular here to begin with.

Comment: No it actually should not have any other reference in JS

Comment: Use if condition otherwise , if you don't want to change name then put your input in if condition with browser or mobile platform check

Comment: Not sure what you mean like server side detect? in this car is not possible because if  you are on desktop and resize the viewport you may hide the form

Comment: @CBroe if you want to write a reply you answer fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique within an HTML document, so no, there is no way to do this without changing the IDs.

> I guess I will not have any issue with post variables if I differentiate ID while keeping field name the same

IDs have no relevance whatsoever in creating the form submission data set. Question would be, whether IDs are actually needed for anything in particular here to begin with.